# Promises are not behaving as I expect them to

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, es6-promise

I'm using Express for routing and Sequelize for DB management.

```
app.get('/api/users/:username', (req, res) => {
  let username = req.params.username;
  findChattersPerRole()
    .then(chattersPerRole => {
      console.log('instakbot should\'ve been added by now...');
    });
});
```

The function findChattersPerRole returns an object with each user's username and role as another object.

```
const findChattersPerRole = () => {
  return fetch('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters')
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(r => {
      let chatters = r.chatters;
      let chattersPerRole = Object.keys(chatters).map(role => {
        return chatters[role].map(username => {
          console.log('findOrCreateViewer will be executed after this');
          findOrCreateViewer(username, role);
          return {
            username: username,
            role: role
          };
        });
      });
      return Promise.resolve(flattenDeep(chattersPerRole));
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error in fetch: ${err}`);
    });
};
```

The problem is, in my route, I expect the `console.log('instakbot should\'ve been added by now...');` to be executed AFTER my viewers got inserted into the database because in my function findChattersPerRole I already insert them with the function findOrCreateViewer. I expect this to happen because in my route I write the console.log when findChattersPerRole() is resolved...

```
const findOrCreateViewer = (username, role) => {

  return Viewer.findOrCreate({
    where: {
      username
    },
    defaults: {
      instakluiten: 5,
      role
    }
  }).spread((unit, created) => {
    console.log('unit is: ', unit.dataValues.username);
    if(created){
      return `created is ${created}`;
    }else{
      return unit;
    }
  });

};
```

However, in my terminal you can see that this is not the way it's happening... Why aren't my promises being executed at the expected time?
[Screenshot of my terminal](https://puu.sh/rVG8U/8e947256f5.png)

Comment: `findOrCreateViewer` seems to be asynchronous, so you want that function to return a promise and do something like `return Promise.all(chattersPerRole);` where `chattersPerRole` is an array of promises (created by `return findOrCreateViewer(username, role).then(() => ({username, role}));` from the `.map` callback).

Comment: So instead of the spread I might say .then(return Promise.resolve(unit));?

Comment: I don't know what `.spread` does. Does it return a promise? If yes, then you probably don't need to change that function, but you have to do something with the return value (as shown in my first comment). Currently you are not  doing anything with it: `findOrCreateViewer(username, role);`.

Comment: Yes spread returns a promise. Oh you lost me after your first edit, I've been working on this issue for so long my head hurts. Why is it exactly a bad thing, or at least not the best decision, in this case, to just call findOrCreateViewer(...)?

Comment: Since you are not doing anything with the returned promise, you don't know when it is "done" (i.e. when data has been inserted) before you continue doing other things. If you depend on asynchronous operations to run in order, you need to wait for each of them to be done, which is what promises gives you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return {username: ...}` after `findOrCreateViewer(username, role);` happens immediately after the function is called and *before* any data has been inserted. That also means that `return Promise.resolve(flattenDeep(chattersPerRole));` happens before any data has been inserted, etc.

You said `findOrCreateViewer` returns a promise, so you need to wait until that promise is resolved (i.e. wait until after the data was inserted) before continuing with something else.

You want `chattersPerRole` to be an array of (arrays of) promises and only proceed *after* all the promises are resolved.

This is easy to do with `Promise.all`:

```
const findChattersPerRole = () => {
  return fetch('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters')
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(r => {
      let chatters = r.chatters;
      let chattersPerRole = Object.keys(chatters).map(
        role => chatters[role].map(username => {
          console.log('findOrCreateViewer will be executed after this');
          return findOrCreateViewer(username, role).then(
            () => ({username, role})
          );
        });
      );
      return Promise.all(flattenDeep(chattersPerRole));
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error in fetch: ${err}`);
    });
};
```

Now the promise returned by `findChattersPerRole` will be resolved *after* all the promises returned by `findOrCreateViewer` are resolved.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain this to me, appreciate it big time. Could you perhaps explain what the difference is exactly between Promise.resolve and Promise.all? I understand now what .all does, but I thought I was doing that already with the .resolve, which I clearly was not. Also, is ``() => ({username, role})`` an ES6 syntax equivalent to return {...}? I assume it is, but I'd rather be sure. Thanks once again for the explanation already mate.

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` is really just a shorthand for `new Promise(resolve => resolve(42))`, i.e. it wraps a value into a promise and resolves it immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Promises are doing no magic. Returning a promise doesn't mean that calling the function will block, but rather that you can easily chain callbacks to do something with the result. You'll need to use

```
function findChattersPerRole() {
  return fetch('https://tmi.twitch.tv/group/user/instak/chatters')
    .then(parseJSON)
    .then(r => {
      let chatters = r.chatters;
      let chattersPerRole = Object.keys(chatters).map(role => {
        return chatters[role].map(username => {
          console.log('findOrCreateViewer will be executed after this');
          return findOrCreateViewer(username, role).then(() => {
//        ^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^
            return {
              username: username,
              role: role
            };
          });
        });
      });
      return Promise.all(flattenDeep(chattersPerRole));
//                   ^^^ get a promise for an array of results from an array of promises
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error in fetch: ${err}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really like the way you point out my mistake by highlighting it in my code and add commentary.